# Static instance is null from service

Tags: android, service, static, singleton

Sometimes the instance of my main class becomes null when calling it from a service.

First thing I stat the singleton by calling "MainClass.init()".
After I call "startOnboarding()" from the singleton MainClass, the service starts.

The "onStartCommand()" method calls the singleton - MainClass.getInstance () and sometimes the value is null.

```
// Singleton
public class MainClass {
    private static MainClass instance = null;
    private String param;

    public static void init(String param) {
        instance = new MainClass(param);
    }

    public static MainClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private MainClass(String param) {
         this.param = param;
    }

    public void startOnboarding(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnboardingService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}

public class OnboardingService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (MainClass.getInstance() == null) {
            // This happened sometimes
            logger.error("NO MAIN INSTANCE");
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        ....
    }

    public class OnboardingServiceBinder extends Binder {
        OnboardingService getService() {
             // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return OnboardingService.this;
        }
    }

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new OnboardingServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Tested on Samsung Galaxy 10.

Can you please help?

Comment: when do you call init ?

Comment: This is a SDK. The init is the first thing the program is calling

Answer (score 0):

Services might be started even if no activity is showing. 
I believe you assume that you initialize your singleton somewhere in your main activity, if so you need to find an earlier point to initialize the singleton (e.g App#onCreate)

Comment: Yes. The first thing I do is staring the singleton by calling init(). Then I'm calling the service from th singleton.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it's probably timing issue initializing your singleton, didn't the solution above help ?

Comment: No. It is initialize OK. Then it is reset.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons should have single method for initializing and accessing it:

```
public static MainClass getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MainClass();
        return instance;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This way the instance will never be null when you need it.

Comment: True. This is not classic singleton. I'm starting it from the method init. This is the first thing I do

Answer (score 0):

The right way to initialize singletone

```
public final class Singleton {
   private static volatile Singleton _instance = null;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
       if (_instance == null)
           synchronized (Singleton.class) {
               if (_instance == null)
                   _instance = new Singleton();
           }
       return _instance;
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks. However I cannot do it in my case. There is any reason that the singleton instance become null?

Comment: return START_STICKY

Comment: In this case your service can be recreated by the system even if you have closed your application. You should initialize singletone in getInstance method.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot do it. This is a SDK. The singleton receive parameters from the program and must remember them.

Comment: From where you are calling method MainClass.init?

Comment: The first thing that the program do with the SDK is to initialize the SDK with MainClass.init(param)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no answer.
See the post:
https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/please-dont-use-singletons-to-persist-state-on-android-7bac9bc78b29